# Datasource too many open connection

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jdbc, struct

I write in the contex.xml:

```xml
<Resource name="1_db" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="50" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" username="root" password="tunespray2008" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"  url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/1_db">
<Resource name="2_db" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="50" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" username="root" password="tunespray2008" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"  url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/2_db">
<Resource name="3_db" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="50" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" username="root" password="tunespray2008" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"  url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/3_db">
<Resource name="common" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="50" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" username="root" password="tunespray2008" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"  url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/common">
```

Java code:

```
public static Connection getDBConnection(String url) 
{
Connection con = null;
    try 
    {
    Context ctx = new InitialContext();
    BasicDataSource ds = (BasicDataSource)tx.lookup("java:comp/env/"+url);
    con = ds.getConnection();
    }catch(Exception e) {}
    return con;
}
```

After that I call:

```
String url ="common";
LoginDAO ldcom = DAOFactory.getLoginDAO(url);
url ="1_db";
LoginDAO ldcom = DAOFactory.getLoginDAO(url);
StatusDAO ldcom = DAOFactory.getStatusDAO(url);
```

After that when we watch through `JProfiler` it shows a lot of open connections, though we call `con.close()`, `rs.close()` or `st.close()`.

Please mention how can we use a `Datasource` in the proper way?

Comment: how about closing the connection in finally block , and isn;t it a bad idea to return a connection in catch block?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 pojnts:

1) **Allways close connections (and other DB resources) in a finally block.** In your case, it might be something:

```
Connection conn = null;
try {
    conn = getDBConnection(xxx);
    // do stuff with the connection
}
// optionally catch any errors that you can handle
finally {
    // close other DB resources that depend on conn, e.g. Statements, ResultSets
    if( conn != null ) try { conn.close(); }
    catch(Exception ignore) {}
}
```

2) **The open connections you are seeing are probably the connection pool**. Creating DB connections with `DriverManager.getConnection()` is an expensive (time consuming) process. In an application server environment, where there are many concurrent requests, creating a new connection per request would be a performance killer. The `javax.sql.Datasource` wraps a connection pool managed by the application server. When you `close()` a connection taken from that pool (the `Datasource`) it is not *destroyed*, rather *returned* to the pool for future usage.

Comment: catch(Exception ignore) {}? why would you ignore the exception, i don't think it should never be ignored, flush it to the logs.